# How to change the internal name of SharePoint Library Column using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-library

I am trying to create a custom column in SharePoint 2013 document library using SharePoint REST API. The column is created but I am not able to change the internal name of the column while creating. Below is my code

```
string metaDataName="Test Column"
string siteUrl = "http://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/testSite/";
string metaDataInternalName = metaDataName.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
JObject json = JObject.Parse("{'__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Field' },'FieldTypeKind': 2,'InternalName': '" + metaDataInternalName + "','StaticName':'" + metaDataInternalName + "','Title': '" + metaDataName + "','Required': true }");
int contentLen = json.ToString().Length;
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user1", "pass@123", "CompanyDomain");
string rESTUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('Library 1')/fields";
var client = new HttpClient(handler);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
var digest = await GetDigestAsync(siteUrl + "/_api/contextinfo", client);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-HTTP-Method", "POST");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-RequestDigest", digest);
HttpContent strContent = new StringContent(json.ToString());
strContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
strContent.Headers.ContentType.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("odata", "verbose"));
strContent.Headers.ContentLength = contentLen;
var response = await client.PostAsync(rESTUrl, strContent);
string res = response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode().StatusCode.ToString();
if (res == "Created")
{
return "MetaData Created";
}
else
{
return "MetaData not created";
}
```

All the other properties like 'FieldTypeKind' and 'Required' are working fine but the internal and static name is not working as expected. So how can we change the column internal name while creating them..??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try `Name` instead of `InternalName` and see if it works.

Comment: @NadeemYousuf : No it is not working. Infact by changing from Internal Name to Name the server returns the Bad Request error

Answer (score 3):

`InternalName` is a readonly property so having it while creating a field may not work. Set your field properties using `SchemaXml` property. See this for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn600182.aspx